# Enumerate possible configurations

Tags: python, computer-science, np

In a computer game you can build four types of units. Each of the units has a certain cost associated with them. Further, you have a limit on how many resources you can spend.

```
limit = 18
costs = [2, 5, 7, 10]
```

Using Python, I want to enumerate all the possible configurations of units you can build. For the example above, valid configurations are:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 (=18)
5 5 5 2 (=17)
10 2 2 2 2 (=18)
10 7 (=17)
...
```

Question: What is this problem called in computer science? I know that there is the [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). Is this a special variant of the Subset sum problem or is it called something else?

Comment: This is knapsack, you want a version that finds all solutions. Should be easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is by using itertools.  The trick here is to calculate the maximum number of couples you can create.  You do this by dividing the limit by the minimum cost.

```
import itertools

limit = 18
costs = [2, 5, 7, 10]

res=[]
nmax=int(limit/min(costs))
for i in range(1,nmax):
    a=itertools.combinations_with_replacement(costs, i)
    a = [list(row) for row in a]
    for j in a:
        if(sum(j)<=limit):
            res.append(j)
print(res)
```

[[2], [5], [7], [10], [2, 2], [2, 5], [2, 7], [2, 10], [5, 5], [5, 7], [5, 10], [7, 7], [7, 10], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 10], [2, 5, 5], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 10], [2, 7, 7], [5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 7], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 2, 10], [2, 2, 5, 5], [2, 2, 5, 7], [2, 2, 7, 7], [2, 5, 5, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 2, 2, 10], [2, 2, 2, 5, 5], [2, 2, 2, 5, 7], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using knapsack, there are variations that print out all possible solutions.

If you want to implement something simpler, but not as efficient on bigger instances you can use a simple recursive function:

```
def f(costs, limit, sofar, _sum ):
    if not costs or limit < 0:
        if limit >= 0:
            print(f"{sofar}(={_sum})")
    else:
        f(costs, limit -costs[0], sofar + str(costs[0])+ " ", _sum + costs[0])
        f(costs[1:], limit, sofar, _sum)


f([2,5,7,10], 18, "", 0)
```

This will give:

```
...
2 5 5 5 (=17)
2 5 5 (=12)
2 5 7 (=14)
2 5 10 (=17)
2 5 (=7)
2 7 7 (=16)
2 7 (=9)
2 10 (=12)
2 (=2)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is closely related to [integer partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))in mathematics.

Imagine making change for some dollar amount. For example, if you make change for $0.87 you can use 3 coins at 25¢ each, plus 1 coin at 10¢, plus 2 coins at 1¢.

```
import functools
import sys
import copy

class PossibilityMaker:
    log_progress = lambda *args, sep=" ", end="\n", print=print, file=sys.stderr:\
        print(*args, sep=sep, end=end, file=file)

    log_progress = lambda *args, **kwargs: None

    @classmethod
    def get_possibilities(cls, total:int, denominations):
        assert(isinstance(total, int))
        denominations = set(denominations)
        possibilities = list()
        cls.get_possibilities_helper(total, denominations, possibilities, dict())
        return possibilities

    @classmethod
    def get_possibilities_helper(cls, total:int, denominations:set, possibilities:list, partial):
        assert(isinstance(total, int))
        cls.log_progress("making change for", total, "cent(s) using coins", denominations)
        if len(denominations) < 1:
            partial = copy.copy(partial)
            partial[1] = total
            possibilities.append(partial)
            cls.log_progress(partial)
            del partial
        else:
            max_denom = max(denominations)
            cls.log_progress("largest coin is", max_denom, "cent(s)")
            max_coin_quantity = total//max_denom
            for coin_quantity in range(max_coin_quantity + 1):
                cls.log_progress("Using", coin_quantity, "of coin of size", max_denom)
                next_partial = copy.deepcopy(partial)
                next_partial[max_denom] = coin_quantity
                next_total = total - coin_quantity * max_denom
                next_denominations = copy.deepcopy(denominations)
                next_denominations.remove(max_denom)
                cls.get_possibilities_helper(next_total, next_denominations, possibilities, next_partial)
            return

possibilities = PossibilityMaker.get_possibilities(18, [2, 5, 7, 10])

print(60*"#")

print(
    "\n".join(
        str(possibility) for possibility in possibilities
    )
)
```

The output is:

```
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 0, 1: 18}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 1, 1: 16}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 2, 1: 14}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 3, 1: 12}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 4, 1: 10}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 5, 1: 8}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 6, 1: 6}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 7, 1: 4}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 8, 1: 2}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 9, 1: 0}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 1, 2: 0, 1: 13}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 1, 2: 1, 1: 11}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 1, 2: 2, 1: 9}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 1, 2: 3, 1: 7}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 1, 2: 4, 1: 5}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 1, 2: 5, 1: 3}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 1, 2: 6, 1: 1}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 2, 2: 0, 1: 8}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 2, 2: 1, 1: 6}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 2, 2: 2, 1: 4}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 2, 2: 3, 1: 2}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 2, 2: 4, 1: 0}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 3, 2: 0, 1: 3}
{10: 0, 7: 0, 5: 3, 2: 1, 1: 1}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 0, 2: 0, 1: 11}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 0, 2: 1, 1: 9}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 0, 2: 2, 1: 7}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 0, 2: 3, 1: 5}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 0, 2: 4, 1: 3}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 0, 2: 5, 1: 1}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 1, 2: 0, 1: 6}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 1, 2: 1, 1: 4}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 1, 2: 2, 1: 2}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 1, 2: 3, 1: 0}
{10: 0, 7: 1, 5: 2, 2: 0, 1: 1}
{10: 0, 7: 2, 5: 0, 2: 0, 1: 4}
{10: 0, 7: 2, 5: 0, 2: 1, 1: 2}
{10: 0, 7: 2, 5: 0, 2: 2, 1: 0}
{10: 1, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 0, 1: 8}
{10: 1, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 1, 1: 6}
{10: 1, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 2, 1: 4}
{10: 1, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 3, 1: 2}
{10: 1, 7: 0, 5: 0, 2: 4, 1: 0}
{10: 1, 7: 0, 5: 1, 2: 0, 1: 3}
{10: 1, 7: 0, 5: 1, 2: 1, 1: 1}
{10: 1, 7: 1, 5: 0, 2: 0, 1: 1}
```

You can treat the 1 cent coins as "leftovers" or "wastage." I realize that you don't actually have 1 cent coins, but everything always adds up to your `limit = 18` if you imagine that the player bought a null/wastage item.